# In Typescript, Declare an interface and define it in different files

Tags: typescript

I am building a software that uses WebSocket with the package NodeJS ws. I organised my networking around a module that is charged of receiving and sending the messages. Because i am using TypeScript, I want to use the type checking which can be pretty handy sometimes. So I constructed two types:

```
// networking.ts
export class Message {
    constructor(
        public request: string,
        public params: Params) {}
}

export interface Params {
    messageId?: number;
}
```

This works fine as long as I am only required to use `messageId` as a parameter. But what if I need to also send a nickname as a parameter ? I could add it to the `Params` definition but I don't want the networking engine to bother to know all the different parameters that can be sent (you can imagine that I have actually more than one parameter to send)...

Is there a way to do something like:

```
// profile-params.ts
export interface Params {
    nickname:string;
}

// admin-params.ts
export interface Params {
    authorizations: string[];
}
```

Such that in the end, the declaration of `Params` can be merged ? I looked at the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) but it can't make it work on different files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@Daniel W Strimpel is ok, if your interface does not come from a module and you are ok with putting it in the global scope.

If you want the interface to be part of a module you could use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to extend the interface:

```
//pModule.ts
export interface Params {
    messageId: number;
}

//pAug.ts
import { Params } from "./pModule";
declare module './pModule' {
    interface Params {
        nickname: string;
    }
}
//usage.ts
import {Params} from './pModule'
import './pAug'

let p : Params = {
    nickname: '',
    messageId: 0
}
```

Comment: I see: the declaration merging on different files only works on module ?

Comment: If you use a module system, the interface will have to reside in a certain module which you have to import and then import the augmentations. You could also declare the interface in global `declare global {
    export interface Params {
        messageId: number;
    }
}` and then the interface will be a global one and you can access it from any file (you ca import the files that contain the global declarations to bring them into scope)

Answer (score 0):

Use generics:

```
export class Message<P extends Params> {
  constructor(
    public request: string,
    public params: P
  ) { }
}

export interface Params {
  messageId?: number
}

// profile-params.ts
export interface ProfileParams extends Params {
  nickname: string
}

const message = new Message<ProfileParams>('', { nickname: 'a' })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully know the reasons why right now (other than the fact that the moment something is exported it is turned into a module), but the only way I know how to accomplish this is to have them in their own individual files where nothing is exported and import the files (without the `{ Params } from` syntax).

```
// ./message/params.model.ts
interface Params {
    messageId?: number;
}

// ./user/params.model.ts
interface Params {
    nickname: string;
}

// ./authorization/params.model.ts
interface Params {
    authorizations: string[];
}

// ./some.component.ts
import './message/params.model.ts';
import './user/params.model.ts';
import './authorization/params.model.ts';

const params: Params = {
    authorizations: ['black-belt', 'secret-service'],
    nickname: 'ninja',
    messageId: 1
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I would have liked to not include every file like you did but I guess it makes more sense to do so